# Add password wrong or not register

Tags: php, mongodb

I want add this message on my login form:

> "password wrong or not register"

I have make `else` after `if($result)` but I have not managed, I am a beginner in php. This is my login php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Login"){
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $error    = array();
    // Username Validation
    if (empty($username)) {
         $error[] = " <h2>  complete username </h2>";
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
         $error[] = " <h2> complete password</h2> ";
    }

        // connexion data
    if (count($error) == 0)
    {
        $host               = 'localhost';
        $database_name      = 'Projet';
        $database_user_name = '';
        $database_password  = '';
        $connection         = new MongoClient();

        if ($connection)
        {
            // select data
            $database = $connection->$database_name;

            // Select collection
            $collection = $database->reg_users;
            $user_data  = array(
                "username" => $username,
                "password" => md5($password)
            );
            $result     = $collection->find($user_data);
            if ($result)
            {
                header("Location: Articles.php");

            } else {
                      $error[] = " no mongodb connection";
                }
        }  


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion is to return a response object whenever a fatal error occurs, at the end of script execution instead of:

```
$error[] = " <h2>  complete username </h2>";
```

We write a function to return a json string using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) with the following keys:

1. status_code (optional) : { String } - you may your own error identifier code
2. success: { boolean } - true or false
3. message: { String } - description
4. data: { your data format } - any data to return

A **response must be returned** either immediately when an `error` occurs (or deferred by design of your code), and on `success` which is at the end of script. For example,

```
<?php
  // validations on $_POST etc.
  ..
  // do stuffs
  // everything ok, completed writing data into db
  return `json_encode($response))`:
?>
```

So, the front end handles the response by evaluating the status codes, or flags, display `message` for both success or error case.

```
// example of response object received via ajax
{
  "success": true, // or false
  "message": "Successfully inserted..", //  or "ERROR: Username and/or password is invalid" 
  "data":[
     // anything to be returned.
  ]
}

// basic validation omitted
if(response.success === false) {
  alert( response.message );
}
```

Given this approach, your php will return a response and exit the script if a fatal error occurs. Otherwise, return on success when the script completes executing.

We can now refactored spme code to let front end handles the response and display the message in `$message` for error messages either via ajax, or php form processing method.

```
<html>
  ..
  <!-- success or error message -->
  <h2> $message </h2>
  ..
</html>
```

## Putting it all together

```
// validations - type error
if($_POST) {

  // validations - form errors
  if(!isset($_POST['submit']) or $_POST['submit'] !== "Login") {
    return _response( false, "ERROR: An error occured." );
  } 

  // validations - field/name must exists and contains value
  if( (!isset($_POST['username']) or $_POST['username'] !== "") or
      (!isset($_POST['password']) or $_POST['password'] !== "")) {
    return _response( false, "ERROR: Invalid username and/or password." );
  }

  // *** SECURITY CONCERNS, stripslash, escape chars.. see below
  $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

  // $data = do db stuffs ( for any errors during this operation, return _response( error... ) ) 

  // everything ok
  return _response( true, "Inserted.", $data );
}

/**
 * This function returns a JSON encoded string.
 *
 * @param {boolean} $success - true if successful, otherwise false 
 * @param {String} $message - a string description of $success flag
 * @param {boolean} $data - data results | ""
 * @return json_encode( array ) 
 */
function _response( $success, $message, $data ) {
  // validations omitted
  return json_encode(array(
     'success' => $success,
      .. /// other stuffs
      )); 
  );
}
```

## Final notes:

- **SECURITY CONCERNS on user input**: Refer to my [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30107477/4749156) or [quora](http://qr.ae/0qQ3Z) answers
- An example of [php-json-response here](http://www.happycode.info/php-json-response/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: your example is difficult for me :/

Comment: ill add another example. just a few lines required

Comment: @asm95 i have updated it with some additional validation on user input for security reasons.